# Change row color on CheckBox check

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with multiple columns and the first one is a CheckBox column. What I want is, when a user checks any row's checkbox, the row color will change (any color). This is what I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "ColCheck" Then
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColCheck").Value = True Then

            Dim isChecked As Boolean = DirectCast(dataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).FormattedValue, [Boolean])
            If isChecked Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work. Any solution?

Comment: It looks like you are checking the Check twice, why is that?  Also allow that the event can and will fire for columns other than your check column.  Debug your code to see which `if` is failing....and why

Comment: ...skip the part about the event firing for other columns - you are checking for that, but you only need to check if `e.ColumnIndex = 0` rather than reading the name

Comment: fixed it sir with this code 

        [Private Sub userdatagrid_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles userdatagrid.Paint
        For i = 0 To userdatagrid.Rows.Count - 1
            If userdatagrid.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
                userdatagrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 187, 187)
            Else
            End If
        Next
    End Sub]

Comment: No no no no.  The event tells you which row to paint via the event args.  Do not loop thru all rows.

Comment: but my code seems to work .....what is wrong with it ?